# iOS - Load image into UIImageView from id in javascript on website

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I was just wondering if it would be possible to pull the id "album_cover" from a website. I need to load it into a `UIImageView`. I also should mention that the link in the code is NOT always the same and does change when the song changes ([Link to what website i'm referring to](http://www.pointzeroradio.com/listen-live.html)), so thats why I can't just take the URL and be done.

I think I might be able to use my code of `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('album_cover').textContent;"` but I am not sure how to load it into the UIImageView

Here is the image data from the website:

```
<div id="album_cover">
<img height="160px" width="160px" id="imgcover" src="http://api.cloudrad.io:8000/art/18a4c00346bccf046900f578b36bd2a5.png?nocache=2" alt="Loading...">
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you probably want to:

1. Parse the element string to get the URL string
2. Use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` to get the image data
3. Use `[UIImage imageWithData:]` to create the `UIImage` object
4. Set the `image` property of your `UIImageView` with your new image

Comment: How would I parse the image?